# TSQL/SQL Server 2008 R2 - Recursive select consolidating self-referenced table Unit and apply SUM on UnitSale and UnitCharge

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been searching here and everywhere and I cant find a proper path to follow on my problem.

Here is the structure I am using:

- Table `[Unit]` - represents an unit of an organization, like Management, General Coordination, Production Team 1, etc.

  This table is self-referenced by his own key on the ParentID column.
- Table `[UnitSale]` - holds fictitious sales data, referencing a specific Unit.
- Table `[UnitCharge]` - hold fictitious costs and charges of a specific Unit.

My goal is to select the Units, from the top-most member of the tree, recursively consolidating its child-Units, by applying SUM on each `UnitSale` and `UnitCharge` of the children, and finally applying theses totals to the current Unit, in this case, the top most.

- Image of sample data: http://brit.dyndns-work.com:89/Brit/SampleData.png
- Check the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75c3cc/3

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE is a good way to go. I would however do it bottom-up attributing sales from lower level to upper level, group by unit and finally join to unit for description and calculate rate. Check the updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75c3cc/16/0.

```
with cte1 as
(
  select u.id, u.parentid, s.salevalue, c.chargevalue
  from Unit u
    left join UnitSale s on s.unitid = u.id
    left join UnitCharge c on c.unitid = u.id

  union all

  select u.id, u.parentid, x.salevalue, x.chargevalue
  from Unit u
    inner join cte1 x on x.parentid = u.id
)
, cte2 as
(
  select id, sum(salevalue) as totalsale, sum(chargevalue) as totalcharge
  from cte1
  group by id
)
select u.id, u.description, u.parentid, x.totalsale, x.totalcharge, x.totalsale / x.totalcharge as rate
from cte2 x
  inner join unit u on u.id = x.id
order by u.description
```

Comment: This is awesome! Its working exactly as I expected it to! Thanks very much!